Is there a way to export RTCSTART to a .txt file using FFmpeg?
Is there a way to export RTCSTART to a .txt file using FFmpeg?
Here is the code I've found so far.
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop 
            -filter_complex setpts=RTCTIME,split[out][ts];[out]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[out] -map [out] 
            -vcodec libx264 
            -pix_fmt yuv420p 
            -preset ultrafast
            -crf 18 
            -y output_video.mkv 
            -map [ts] 
            -f mkvtimestamp_v2 video_output_timestamp_data.txt 
            -vsync 0

This works, but I wonder if it would be possible to find a best approach or simply extract the RTCTIME of the first frame?

Do you mean saving only the first timecode. Try: ... -f mkvtimestamp_v2 -frames:v 1 video_output_timestamp_data.txt. You may also print the timecode to stdout: ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -v error -t 1 -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -filter_complex setpts=RTCTIME,split[out][ts];[out]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[out] -map [out] -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -y output_video.mkv -map [ts] -f mkvtimestamp_v2 -frames:v 1 pipe: -vsync 0 | grep -v "#"

Thanks for your reply ! I will use the stdout as you mentionned. Do you know if there is some sort of "mp4timestamp" ?

I don't think there is "mp4timestamp", but I didn't knew about mkvtimestamp_v2 before reading your question, so maybe there is. As far as I remember MKV uses a fixed timebase of 1000 ticks per second (timestamps in milliseconds) when used with FFmpeg. With MP4 we may select the timebase. When converting the time to seconds, there is no difference between MKV and MP4.
